# Is it posible to have last column sticky in a table with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm doing some app and in the Figma the last column in the tables are sticky.

I know It's achievable to stick the first row and the first column and it's awesome.

Check the code here.
https://css-tricks.com/a-table-with-both-a-sticky-header-and-a-sticky-first-column/

Should be something like

```
table thead th:last-child {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

table tbody td:last-child {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

I made a lot of POC but no success.

Did someone achieve this?

Comment: Hello, can you post a code snippet of what you have done?

Comment: The edited code should work (last column must be sticky to the right)

Comment: Yes, I edited because the issue was the position....

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use css rule `position: sticky` and `right: 0` for the last table column and add some style to make it look like a table cell (just to avoid overlapping of the other cells content)

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;  
}

table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table th:last-child,
table td:last-child {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
}

table th:last-child:before,
table td:last-child:before {
  content: "\00a0";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

div {
  max-width: 160px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
        <th>Col Sticky</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
        <td>Cell Sticky</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```